# I reinstalled XAMMP, and now none of my servers are working and local host is showing "Access denied" (Mac)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

This is my error when I go to my local host -> PHPMyAdmin

MySQL said: Documentation

> Cannot connect: invalid settings.
> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory
> Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory
> phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

Anyone know how to fix this? Im on Mac.

Comment: Phpmyadmin needs to be reconfigured (re install pma db)

Comment: how would I do that?

Comment: I don't use xampp so i can't help you with the details. But pma needs db access to run. Look for config options and verify login details for your db